# Perl Moose - Loading values from configuration file etc

Tags: perl, moose

I'm new to using Moose, but I was wondering how I can load values from a configuration file and then exposing those values as properties of my 'config' object where the attributes are the configuration names in the configuration file.

For example,
The configuration file might contain:

```
server:mozilla.org
protocol:HTTP
```

So I'd like my config object to have a 'server' attribute with a value of 'mozilla.org' and a protocol attribute with a value of 'HTTP'.

Right now my understanding is that I have to explicitly name the attributes with a

```
has 'server'  => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'mozilla.org' );
```

type of entry in my Config.pm file.

How do I dynamically create these so that the configuration file can change without having me rewrite the Config.pm each time that it does?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite what you asked for, but you can get a `config` attribute that's a hash reference by using [`BUILDARGS`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0402/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod#BUILDARGS) to populate the config info at the time of creation.  Assuming that the lines of your config file consist of key-value pairs separated by `:`, something like this should work:

```
package My::Module;
use Moose;

has 'config'=>(isa=>'HashRef[Str]',is=>'rw',required=>1);

around BUILDARGS=>sub
{
  my $orig=shift;
  my $class=shift;
  my $args=shift; #other arguments passed in (if any).

  my %config_hash=();
  open(my $read,"<","config_file") or confess $!;
  while(<$read>)
  {
    chomp;
    my @array=split /:/;
    $config_hash{$array[0]}=$array[1];
  }
  close($read);

  $args->{config}=\%config_hash;

  return $class->$orig($args);
};

no Moose;
1;
```

With minimal effort, it's also easy to have additional attributes to specify the name and path of the config file along with the delimiter.  These could be accessed inside of `BUILDARGS` as, eg, `$args->{config_file}` and `$args->{config_delimiter}`.

Comment: I have to slap myself on the head because it seems so obvious now.  I think I was believing it should be more "moosey".  Which was some vague fear that it would require me thinking in a completely orthogonal fashion.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries.  :)  `BUILDARGS` is extremely handy, and once I grokked it (as the kids nowadays say it), I found myself using it quite a bit.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I've got another question that might be best if I could just send you an email.  Would that be possible?

Comment: If it's another code question, feel free to open up another question on Stackoverflow.  If you'd like, though, my email address is `jackmaney at gmail dot com`.

Comment: It's a question related to implementing the example you gave above.  I'm trying to tie in Config:Auto.  Should I edit the above question or create a new one and reference this question?

Comment: Go ahead and start a new question that references this one.

Answer (score 7):

That's such an obvious idea, it has been implemented already several times.

- [MooseX::ConfigFromFile](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aConfigFromFile)
- [MooseX::Configuration](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aConfiguration)
- [MooseX::SimpleConfig](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aSimpleConfig)

Also see

- [MooseX::App](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aApp)
- [MooseX::App::Cmd](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aApp%3a%3aCmd)
- [MooseX::Runnable](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aRunnable)

which map command-line options to attributes, which you most likely also want.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use the tools that have already been written and tested by others.