# Perl Moose - What are the arguments when Loading valued from configuration files?

Tags: perl, moose

In my previous question [Moose - Loading values from conf files...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777982/perl-moose-loading-values-from-configuration-file-etc) Jack Maney was kind enough to provide an example of how to do so using Moose.

In order to make the configuration object even more general I decided to use [Config::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-Auto/lib/Config/Auto.pm).

The problem is that I still am very green as to how Moose works.  For instance, Jack's example is:

```
package My::Module;
use Moose;

has 'config'=>(isa=>'HashRef[Str]',is=>'rw',required=>1);

around BUILDARGS=>sub
{
  my $orig=shift;
  my $class=shift;
  my $args=shift; #other arguments passed in (if any).

  my %config_hash=();
  open(my $read,"<","config_file") or confess $!;
  while(<$read>)
  {
    chomp;
    my @array=split /:/;
    $config_hash{$array[0]}=$array[1];
  }
  close($read);

  $args->{config}=\%config_hash;

  return $class->$orig($args);
};

no Moose;
1;
```

I had modified it to this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
package DART::Setup;

use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;
use Config::Auto;

our $VERSION = '0.0.1';


has 'EMPTY' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', default => q{} );
has 'PPLTESTEXECUTIONID' => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'ro', default => 0 );
has 'SARQTESTEXECUTIONID' => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'ro', default => 0 );
has 'ISPROXY' => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'ro', default => 0 );
has 'LOCALHOST' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', default => '127.0.0.1' );
has 'config'=>(isa=>'HashRef[Str]',is=>'rw',required=>1);
has 'SSO' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', default => q{} );
has 'cookieFile' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', default => q{} );

around BUILDARGS=>sub
{
  my $orig=shift;
  my $class=shift;
  my $args=shift;

  my $cfg = Config::Auto::parse($args);
  my %config_hash = %{$cfg};

  $args->{config}=\%config_hash;

  return $class->$orig($args);
};


return 1;
```

But to be honest I'm not sure what I'm doing here.  First off, how many arguments do I need to provide when I'm creating a new Setup object?  Do I just pass it the path to my configuration file, something like:

```
my $newConfig = DART::Setup->new('/home/y/conf/MyApp/MyApp.cfg');
```

Or do I need to provide arguments for $orig and $class?

Finally, how do I now access my newly loaded configurations?  Can I do something like:

```
my %configHash = %{$newConfig->config()};

foreach my $key (keys %configHash) {
print "the key is, $key, and the value is: $configHash{$key}\n";
}
```

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, inside of `BUILDARGS`, you want to read in the config file and pass the key-value pairs into the `config` attribute.  Here's a modified version with another attribute for the config file.

```
package My::Module;
use Moose;
use Config::Auto;

has 'config'=>(isa=>'HashRef[Str]',is=>'rw',required=>1);

has 'config_file'=>(isa=>'Str',is=>'ro');

around BUILDARGS=>sub
{
  my $orig=shift;
  my $class=shift;
  my $args=shift; #currently {config_file=>'/path/to/file/config_file.conf'} (or whatever)

  #make sure we've been passed a config file
  confess "No config file found in BUILDARGS" unless defined $args->{config_file};

  #Now, we open the user-specified config file via Config::Any
  my $ca=Config::Auto->new(source=>$args->{config_file},format=>"colon");
  my $parsed=$ca->parse; #hash reference containing the parsed data.

  #Now, we add this to our arguments that will become our attributes:

  $args->{config}=$parsed;

  return $class->$orig($args);
}

no Moose;
1;
```

The main thing to realize about `BUILDARGS` is that it takes the following arguments:  the names of the class and original constructor (which are passed to `Moose::Object`) and then any other arguments passed to the constructor.  So, if you call

```
my $mm=My::Module->new({config_file=>"/path/to/file/file.conf"});
```

Then, in `BUILDARGS`, we initially have

```
$args=={config_file=>"/path/to/file/file.conf"}
```

But after parsing the file and adding the `$parsed` hash reference, it turns into

```
$args=={config_file=>"/path/to/file/file.conf",config=>{server=>"mozilla.org",protocol=>"HTTP",...}}
```

etc, etc.

By writing `my $cfg = Config::Auto::parse($args);` inside of `BUILDARGS`, you're trying to pass a `config_file` argument to the parser in `Config::Auto`, and it'll have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Hmmm, when I call my $newConfig = DART::Setup->new({config_file=>"/home/y/conf/smoker/smkr.cfg"}); I'm getting "No config file found! line 36" which is the line containing "confess "No config file found in BUILDARGS" unless $args->{config_file};"

Comment: Hmmm, just before the confess line, put in `use Data::Dumper;print Dumper($args) . "\n";` and see what it prints out.

Comment: $VAR1 = {
          'config_file' => '/home/y/conf/smoker/smkr.cfg'
        };
 BTW, thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, so it has the right data...change the `unless` statement to `unless defined $args->{config_file}` (as in the edited code above).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that, as I mentioned below, we have a corporate software control system and perl modules aren't aways the most current available.  The version of Config:Auto that we have doesn't have the OO interface so I had to substitute the older way of parsing the file.  I made a syntax error when I did so and now it sort of works, except that moose is throwing an error about "Use of uninitialized value in hash element".  I think it's related to the fact that some of my configuration values have nasty characters like colons and semi-colons in them.

Comment: Yes, if the configuration value contains spaces or other funky characters Moose throws a "type constraint" validation error because Config:Auto returns that as a hash reference apparently.

Comment: Well you can relax the `isa` on `config` to `HashRef[Any]`, but then you'll have to worry about the structure of `$self->config` in any other methods that you use.

Answer (score 1):

`BUILDARGS` is just a way to hook into the constructor at the beginning of construction. For your reference, the [construction section of the manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aConstruction) might help in your understanding on that.

Jack Maney's answer is perfectly fine. Building on his suggestion to use a `config_file` attribute, here's an alternative that uses a [lazy builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aAttributes#Default-and-builder-methods). Personally, I prefer these to BUILDARGS because the code is slightly simpler. Builders are used to set the default value of an attribute. You need to make it lazy because building the attribute depends on another attribute (in this case `config_file`) to ensure that construction of the object has completed and the attribute has been set.

```
package DART::Setup;

use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;
use MooseX::FileAttribute;
use Config::Auto;

# use MooseX::FileAttribute (optional) to enforce that the file actually exists
#  - just a shortcut to remove some boilerplate code if you want
has_file 'config_file' => (
    is         => 'ro',
    must_exist => 1,
    required   => 1,
);

has 'config' => (
    isa      => 'HashRef[Str]', 
    is       => 'ro',
    # disallow this attribute to be set by the constructor
    init_arg => undef,
    # cause this attribute to be set up after construction
    lazy     => 1,
    builder  => '_build_config',
    # or alternatively, use 'default' instead of 'builder'
    # (but it still needs to be lazy)
    #default  => sub { Config::Auto::parse( shift->config_file ) },
);

sub _build_config {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    my $config = Config::Auto::parse( $self->config_file );
    return $config;
}
```

Comment: We have a corporate software control system that disallows any perl modules that haven't been "officially" ported over.  MooseX::FileAttribute is one of those modules, unfortunately.