# MooseX using Config::Std

Tags: perl, oop, configuration, moose

I'm trying to read a config file with the format

```
<tag>:<value>
```

but I'm having no luck with any of the modules mentioned in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777982), as the Moose modules referred all seem to favour the config.ini style

```
<tag>=<value>
```

which I can't use because I've already got a lot of config files with the `:` notation.

Can I override the method in [`MooseX::Configuration`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Configuration) which uses [`Config::INI::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI::Reader) by a method which uses [`Config::Std`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Std) in an easily maintainable way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can use [`MooseX::ConfigFromFile`](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX::ConfigFromFile) and implement the `get_config_from_file` method like this

```
sub get_config_from_file {
  my ($class, $file) = @_;
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
  scalar { map { chomp; split /:/, $_, 2 } <$fh> };
}
```

Comment: It sort of works, the config goes in, but how do I retreive the attributes I've initialised in the config? If I add an attribute username, say, and set a username field in the config, $config->username produces nothing. Tried setting lazy builds, and even looking at the config object, but the hash just seems to disappear. TIA

Comment: The problem is GetOpt. Config::Std produces a hash of hashes. GetOpt, unsurprisingly, doesn't like it as the C/L can't understand a hash of hashs, hash of arrays etc. Sort of makes MooseX::ConfigFromFile useless for anything above <tag>:<values> lists. Cheers.